# Downloading a pdf file from JSP file in Java

Tags: spring

I want to download one of my JSP pages as PDF. For example, this is my function which returns to JSP page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String cart(HttpSession httpSession ,final Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    StudentData studentData =(StudentData)httpSession.getAttribute("student");

    if(studentData ==null){
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("isFromCartFlag", Boolean.TRUE);
        return REDIRECT_PREFIX + "/login" ;
    }

    final List<ProductData> cartDataFromDb = listofProducts.retrieveCartEntriesFromDb(studentData.getName());
    List<ProductData> sessionCart = (List<ProductData>) httpSession.getAttribute("sessionCart");
    if (sessionCart != null) {

        for (ProductData sessionCartEntryData : sessionCart) {
            for (ProductData cartEntryData : cartDataFromDb) {
                if(cartEntryData.getProductName().equalsIgnoreCase(sessionCartEntryData.getProductName())){
                    int quantityOfItem = cartEntryData.getQuantity()+sessionCartEntryData.getQuantity();
                    sessionCartEntryData.setQuantity(quantityOfItem);
                }
            }
            listofProducts.insertCartEntriesIntoDb(studentData.getName(),sessionCartEntryData.getProductName(),sessionCartEntryData.getQuantity());
        }
    }


    final List<ProductData> cartData = listofProducts.retrieveCartEntriesFromDb(studentData.getName());
    List<ProductData> productDataListForCart = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
    for (ProductData cartDataEntry : cartData) {
        ProductData productData = listofProducts.displayProductDetailsFromProductId(cartDataEntry.getProductName());
            if(productData.getProductName().equalsIgnoreCase(cartDataEntry.getProductName())){

                cartDataEntry.setBasePrice(productData.getBasePrice());
                cartDataEntry.setDiscout(productData.getDiscout());
                cartDataEntry.setProductImagePath(productData.getProductImagePath());

                productDataListForCart.add(cartDataEntry);
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("listOfProducts", productDataListForCart);
    model.addAttribute("studentData", httpSession.getAttribute("student"));

    if(productDataListForCart.isEmpty()){
        model.addAttribute("isCartEmptyFlag", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    return "CartPage";
}
```

This function displays `cartPage` and I want to display a link on this cart page so that if I click on that link the get page will be downloaded as a PDF file with the same format as it displayed in JSP page. This is how my page looks like, in case you're interested: [image: my page about hamburgers]

Comment: The basic process it outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27533212/1356423

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Web MVC with PDF View Example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x) outlines an approach.  In summary, you implement a bean that extends Spring's [AbstractView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractView.html).  This view accepts the model from Spring MVC which you can then use to render the PDF using the API of your choice.  The article uses a ResourceBundleViewResolver to map the view name to a bean but I personally prefer to use a BeanNameViewResolver.

Spring does provide an AbstractPdfView class but use ann older version of iText for its implementation.